# Sequelize : SQLITE_ERROR: near "[]": syntax error

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize (6.3.0) with sqlite3 (4.2.0) for my database and I'm trying to define the following model :

```js
this.define("giveaways", {
            channel: {
                type: Sq.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            },
            message: {
                type: Sq.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            },
            name: {
                type: Sq.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            },
            end: {
                type: Sq.DATE,
                allowNull: false
            },
            participating: {
                type: Sq.ARRAY(Sq.STRING),
                allowNull: false,
                defaultValue: []
            },
            winnersCount: {
                type: Sq.NUMBER,
                allowNull: false
            },
            winners: {
                type: Sq.ARRAY(Sq.STRING),
                allowNull: false,
                defaultValue: []
            },
            finished: {
                type: Sq.BOOLEAN,
                allowNull: false,
                defaultValue: false
            },
            host: {
                type: Sq.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            }

        });
```

It is supposed to be defined when process starts, but I get the following error :

```
(node:22440) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: near "[]": syntax error
```

And of course whenever I try to do any action to this table, I get follow error :

```
(node:22440) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: giveaways
```

I guess the problem comes from "participating" and "winners" rows that are using the ARRAY data type..

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me quote the [manual](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/api/datatypes/#array):

> `ARRAY()`
>
> An array of `type`, e.g. `DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.DECIMAL)`. **Only available in postgres.**

(Emphasis mine.)

So, you cannot use the `ARRAY` datatype with SQLite3, only with PostgreSQL as your backend.

You can also look at the [SQLite3 docs](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) - SQLite3 doesn't have an array-like datatype that Sequelize could use to implement `ARRAY`.

*On a side note: You should check your code to see why you are getting unhandled promise rejections. It sounds as if you are not handling async errors correctly. Maybe missing `.catch` on an asynchronous call?*